# Send telegram message periodically using bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Give the code below:

```
def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")
```

Is it possible to call this function periodically and make my bot send the message to the user automatically instead of the user typing "/start"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to create a `job` object which is delivered by `python-telegram-bot` 
so to simply run the function `start` let's say every minute you could use this approach:

```
j= updater.job_queue

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

j.run_repeating(start,interval = 60  ,first= 0 )
updater.start_polling()
```

and if you wanted to run it every day at specific time you could use:

```
import datetime 
j= updater.job_queue

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

t= datetime.time(6, 15, 00, 000000)

j.run_daily(start, t, days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), context=None, name=None)
updater.start_polling()
```

note that there's no handlers to be added to the dispatcher.

and you probably should know that the `datetime.time` object uses the UTC time if not modified.

for more information check [Extensions – JobQueue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47299839/4772764) helps with your question. Secondly what I can recommend you is to have a look at Flask and Node-RED. From [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-watson-chatbot-on-nodered/), I think you would understand how to create your structure easily.